# Fail to Connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I just install Team Foundation Server on one computer(computer name is “myserver”), with the basic configuration, below is the details in Team Foundation Server Console:

Notification URL: http://myserver:8080/tfs
Server URL: http://localhost:8080/tfs
Web Access URL: http://myserver:8080/tfs/web

Now I try to follow the instructions in book “Professional Team Foundation Server 2010”, Chapter 3.4, to connect to the Team Foundation Server from another client computer. Based on the book, I just need to input the “Server URL” above, but that is “localhost”, so I choose to input Notification URL instead, but the connection still fails, and it said “the remote name could not be resolved: myserver”. Why?

My client computer and the server is not in the same subnetwork. Will that cause the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Just check the connectivity between your client and the TFS server. Can they ping eachother? And can you access the tfs server with the URL on the AT machine (TFS server installed on)?  BTW, Why are you insisting on TFS 2010? It's ancient and no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you. I try to put the client and the TFS server in the same subnet. Then I can connect to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is putting the client and the TFS server in the same subnet.

Whatever, for the `Fail to connect` issue, you need to ensure the connectivity is OK between the client and server. If they cannot ping eachother, then you need to debug the network/settings to make it work.